# MyFaces on Wildfly - io.undertow.request ERROR : UT005023: Exception handling request to %s

Tags: jsf, jboss, wildfly, myfaces

My JSF application running successfully with  tomacat and websphere After migrated to Jboss, application not stared and getting below exception

io.undertow.request ERROR  :  UT005023: Exception handling request to %s

Please suggest how to resolve this issue

exception stack trace:
 WARNING [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/com/vcc/vct/sgtApp/agvmessages/sender/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
 WARNING [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/com/vcc/vct/sgtApp/cert/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
 WARNING [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/ui/jsfhelpers/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
 WARNING [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/ui/locale/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) Reading config : vfs:/C:/Jboss/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/sgtAppEAR-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-4.0.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) MyFaces Bean Validation support enabled
INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER' found.
 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS' found.
 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW' found, using default value 'false'.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_TAG_EXCEPTIONS_AS_CONTEXT_AWARE' found, using default value 'true'.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS' found, using default value 'noCache'.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY' found.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.INITIALIZE_ALWAYS_STANDALONE' found, using default value 'false'.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.LOG_WEB_CONTEXT_PARAMS' found, using default value 'auto'.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INITIALIZER' found.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.WebConfigParamsLogger] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INIT_PLUGINS' found.
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
  INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) MyFaces already initialized
 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 257) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/sgtAppEAR-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "sgtAppEAR-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "sgtAppEAR-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) *************************************************************************************************************
INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Loading connection pool
 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) *************************************************************************************************************
 io.undertow.request ERROR  :  UT005023: Exception handling request to %s
] io.undertow.request ERROR  :  UT005022: Exception generating error page %s

Comment: Is there a chance to have the entire stack trace added to your question? What JSF versions does your app depend on? Which version of JBoss? How do you deploy? EAR, WAR? Your question is lacking plenty of information making it hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for reply, i run application through eclipse. below are jar related details                     
   server version wildfly14.1 , myfaces-api-2.1.10  and myfaces-impl-2.1.10 jars. i added exception stack trace also please check once

Comment: I don't see the multi lined stack trace with its' "Caused by" statements. Doesn't your log include something like this? The more details you provide, the more likely someon viewing this question is able to give actual advices on your issue. So far I'm only giving advices yet on [ask]

Comment: Theres a suggestion repeated here `Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.` as well as other suggestions above that also related to maven

Comment: Why are you running on wildfly 14 and not using myfaces 2.3?

Comment: @jglass:runnimg on wildfly and thrn usomg a jetty start command is strange to say the least